# Weird network traffic on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, internet, ufw

I noticed abnormal network activity when trying to test something and I can't find what program is the culprit.

Wireshark:
[image: wireshark log]

My local IP is 192.168.100.5

I tried to inspect with `sudo netstat -latpen` and `sudo lsof -i` but there's no trace of it. Only on `sudo iftop -pPl` and `sudo pktstat -i enp7s0 -nt` works but it's not revealing what process is sending pings.

iftop:

[image: iftop log]

This can be seen using `sudo tcpdump ip proto \\icmp` command but that's all, I can't see this on any other tool.
And I inspected all programs that could use it.
I have UFW enabled and blocking port 7759 (IPv4/IPv6) but it doesn't work.

How could I locate the program that sends all these pings?

Comment: See also `curl http://node-241.cheese-onion.nl` which may give a hint, possibly?

Comment: Looks like it's a protocol associated with Tribler which is a torrent and onion routing related tool. I wouldn't be surprised that this protocol triggers connections from unknown peers just like any torrent download would. OP could give more feedback about its use. To check which tool: **as root** (ie: on Ubuntu use sudo): `ss -aunp sport == 7759` (your netstat checked TCP while it's UDP).

Comment: @A.B I guess you're right, I have Tribler installed. The strange thing is that it's not running at all! I installed it as Flatpak without background permission and somehow still this is running (but also there's no Tribler process or something related to it). There's a way to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `iptables` instead of `ufw`.
UFW works at the software level, where IPTables works at the kernel level:

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 7759,7760 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 7759,7760 -j DROP
```